# Как ввести null в консоль IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, консоль, input, null

Пишу Java программу. Для того, чтобы остановить цикл ввода значений в список, нужно ввести null. Клавиша Enter не работает, а слово "null" принимает за строку и выводит исключение. Как ввести null?

Вот код цикла:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> coll = new ArrayList<>();
int full = 0;
while(true) {
    System.out.print("Enter " + (coll.size() + 1) + "number in 
        collection (press enter to exit): ");
    Integer element = (Integer)new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    if (element != null) {
        coll.add(element);
        full += element;
    } else {
         for (int el = 0; el < coll.size(); el++) {
             System.out.println((el + 1) + " element in collection: " + 
                coll.get(el));
         }
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Collection addition result: " + full);
         break;
}
```

Comment: Никак не ввести. То, что вводится в консоль - это строки, а то, как их воспринимать уже зависит от самой программы - например, если она ожидает ввода чисел, то попробует введенную строку в число привести

Comment: @gil9red Извините, но я вас не совсем понял. Можете обьяснить, как заставить программу понимать, что пользователь ничего не ввел? Когда я нажимаю Enter, происходит перенос строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал алгоритм так, чтобы сканер считывал строки, проверяя их на пустоту и для не пустых строк выполняется парсинг в число

Пример:

```
ArrayList<Integer> coll = new ArrayList<>();
int full = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter " + (coll.size() + 1) + "number in collection (press enter to exit): ");
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }

    Integer element = Integer.parseInt(line);
    coll.add(element);
    full += element;
}

for (int el = 0; el < coll.size(); el++) {
    System.out.println((el + 1) + " element in collection: " + coll.get(el));
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Collection addition result: " + full);
```

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую переписать его, чтобы он считывал пробел за пустую строку :)